# Rails4 & Devise: Differentiate two roles at sign- up, one have to confirm, the second not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, roles, hidden-field

I have an rails app with two kinds of users:

**The captain**, which receives the role 'captain' at sign-up (via form A) and has to confirm via email

**The teammate**, which is created by the captain (form B)and receive the Teammate role, do not receive confirmation email, and can't login to the app for now.

Both are in the User model with different role (User.role)

I did this to assign the role to the captain when sign-up :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_create :assign_default_role

    def assign_default_role
     self.role = captain
    end
```

It works.
Now I would like to configure the same thing for Teammate, that would assign the 'teammate' role and skip the activation process.

With Devise I can use **skip_confirmation_notification!** on **before_create** but how can I differenciate Captain Users and Teammates Users at creation?

Since they have the same model and everything is the same in database except "**role**" & later "**confirmed_at**" columns.

**HIDDEN FIELD ?** I tried using an hidden_field "confirmation" with value false in the Teammate form but I'm not sure it's the best way to go, and there is no :confirmation row inside User Model, so I do not know how to pass it to the before_create action.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :confirmation, options = {value: false} %>
```

**CREATE_TEAMMATE Method ?** A secondary create method inside the Users Controller, but that sounds even less good.

Thank you very much for any

```
self.skip_confirmation_notification!
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 'confirmation' as a hidden field is not secure because anyone could edit it in their browser and you could end up in a inconsistent state where a user has the teammate role and have received the confirmation e-mail. This seems not to be something you would want.

If, and only if, your users are free to choose if they want to be a captain or a teammate, you could add a hidden field stating which role should be created. On your before_create callback you would just check the contents of `params['role']` for predefined values (in this case == 'captain' or == 'teammate') and take the appropriate actions.

But if a teammate user can only be created by a captain, you should use the previous method I described but also check if `current_user.role == 'captain'` before one could create a teammate.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm looking for a better way to do that than hidden field but can not figure it for now...
Basically, each user that sign-up (home form) are captain by default (they do not tick a box), the people they add on their teams are teammates by default (no box neither)(secondary form), both in the same model because Teammates can become Captain by signing-up.

I think that you highlighted the fact that captain must be logged to create teammate, and teammate won't be able to log before update to captain. So I can filter with current_user.try

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit of a similar case, in my app user upon registration choose to create a freelance account or an agency account. I fixed that simply by creating my own registration controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_action :set_account_type

  def create
    @user = User.new user_params

    if @account_type == 'captain'
      # Do some stuff related to captain account
      @user.role = 'captain'

    elsif @account_type == 'teammate'
      # Do some stuff related to teammate account
      @user.role = 'teammate'
      @user.skip_confirmation_notification!

    end

    if @user.save
      redirect_to user_registered_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

private

  def set_account_type
    # We ensure that the account_type coming from the registration form is valid
    raise 'Error message OR for validation error' unless %w[captain teammate].include? params[:account_type]
    @account_type = params[:account_type]
  end
end
```

I assume you know how to set up your routes to do so?

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey, thank you for these explanations.
The thing is that none of my user choose the type of user their are : captain choose to use the app to build team so it is assigned captain by default (home sign-up form) and, when he add teammates to his team, those are assigned teammate by default. Later on, maybe they will be captain if they want it. So i do not know how to detect the account type other than a hidden field, for now. Thank you!